# detect what javascript made an AJAX call in IE9

Tags: javascript, debugging, networking, internet-explorer-9, trace

I am working on an enterprise web site that runs on IE only. Some times some script makes an AJAX call to the server. I need to find the javascript code that makes this request. How can I do it in IE9? The code executes by itself so I think that I should either manually find where it is called (the unpreferred way) or find out the place in the code based on some network trace. But I couldn't find any references of the javascript in the network trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 8+ has a built-in developer toolbar with a [*profiler*](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/11/introducing-the-ie8-developer-tools-jscript-profiler.aspx&ei=od_bTZHDHOT30gGeyvm5Dw&usg=AFQjCNHqJSGHGnnan9iCk0yhJSrRIC8r_A) you can use to monitor scripts.  You can access it by hitting [`F12`], select the |`Profiler`| Tab and then press ***start***.